# Can you update a controller that updates it's child scopes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope, parent

Lets say I have a controller & directive like so:

```
app.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
    $scope.loading = true;
    $scope.updateTest = function(){
        $scope.loading = false;
    }
}).directive('loading', function() {
    return {
        restrict : 'E',
        transclude: true, // use parent scope
        link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('loading', function(ctx) {
                console.log('updating?', ctx)
            });
        }
    }
});
```

And a html markup:

```
<section ng-controller="mainController">
    <loading ng-show="loading">
        loading?
    </loading>
    <button ng-click="updateTest()">Force update</button>
</section>
```

I just want to know how to watch the parent scope from within a directive, I can't seem to get this working!

I'm using `Angular 1.3.16`

Comment: Have you tried with '$parent.loading'

Comment: I thought using $parent was technically wrong, as it's an internal variable from all I've read that is not the `angular` way to do it @entre

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/divm/84oLx749/

Comment: The watcher works. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use isolate scope like this and pass all variables throw it:

```
.directive('loading', function() {
  return {
    restrict : 'E',
    scope: {
      ngModel: '='
    },
    transclude: true, // use parent scope
    link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch('ngModel', function(ctx) {
            console.log('updating?', ctx)
        });
    }
  }
});
```

Html

```
<loader ng-model="loading" ng-show="loading">
    loading?
</loader>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you create a directive with scope:false parameter it will use it's parent's scope so you can access and manipulate everything within parent scope. but you are making your directive tightly coupled to parent scope which is not recommended. i would recommend you to use isolate scope and use parameters for this action. by using isolate scopes, your directive will be re-usable

here is how to use parent scope anyways

```
.directive('loading', function() {
return {
restrict : 'E',
scope: false, // use parent scope
transclude: true,
link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$watch('loading', function(ctx) {
        console.log('updating?', ctx)
    });
 }
}
 });
```

Edit: as @zeroFlogL mentioned in comments, not adding a scope is default behaviour of angular. if you delete scope: false section from directive it will work same as scope:false

Comment: Not creating a scope is the default anyway.

Comment: This is exactly the same as my OP :/

Answer (score 1):

When you are using isolate scope as in Tek's answer (which I too would suggest), it might be better to use your own attribute name instead of ngModel, which would only induce the overhead of angular having to process the `ngModel` directive's compile and link (controller) steps.

It's admittedly nitpicky, but working with angular I think it's useful to consider the things going on beneath the surface. In the end, all the angular magic going on isn't "free of charge" and when you are working with real big datasets and generate *n* instances of your directive with `ng-repeat`, in my experience, unnecessary controller instances and watches will add up to performance real quickly.